# does it need mysql server to be running for php_mysql.dll extension to load

Tags: php, mysql, windows, iis-7, installation

I have a Windows Vista PC with IIS7, I have managed to manually install PHP on it.
And managed to load one of my custom extension for PHP, as well as mbstring extension.

But my mysql extension does not load when I check through phpinfo, I checked all the path variable, uncommented requied lines in php.ini file, also verified that the file exists.

My question is, does it require mysql server to be working on the local host for the mysql extension to load? or what could be wrong?

Comment: do you need IIS to run php ?? i would strongly recommend doing as Marc B suggested and install WAMP (which can also be run in conjunction with IIS if need be - change port from 80 to 8080)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, php_mysql.dll simply adds the various mysql functions into PHP. How could the .dll know where your server is? Or how you connect to it? Or what if you've got multiple seperate servers?

Until you actually try to connect to the server, the .dll will happily stay idle and not do anything.

If you're not stuck with using IIS, you could investigate installing [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) - that'll give you MySQL, PHP, and Apache with a nice unified installer, without forcing you to mess around with .dll installation/customization.

Answer (score 5):

No, but you do need the appropriate MySQL *client* libraries to be available.